# Telerik Grid Events not genereted in cs file

Tags: c#, telerik-grid

I am using the Rad grid in HTML code and want to code something in cs file on its Following events.

> NeedDataSource Event, ItemDataBound Event, Item Event...etc

but like VB , here I cant select the control and select that particular control's all events.

In VB I am getting the facility to select and generate all the events of that page. Here in C# code behind I couldn't find that events.

Please tell me how that events are generated in C# code behind page.

Comment: But I don't see any code here, so I'm not sure what this question is about. What is the specific problem that needs to be solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
TelerikGridViewID.ItemDataBound += TelerikGridViewID_ItemDataBound ;
```

You need to add this on Page_Load of the page. After that create method like this with correct EventArguments.

```
public void TelerikGridViewID_ItemDataBound (object sender, Telerik.Web.UI.GridItemEventArgs e)
{
    //code here
}
```

Comment: But in C# cant it be created automatically as like we do for button from properties window...????

Comment: @WilmanPatel you can add to the grid OnItemDataBound="TelerikGridViewID_ItemDataBound" and click create event if you are using VS 2013(I'm not sure if this feature exist in 2012). If the answer helped you accept it.